# SVG Image as icon for AppBarToggleButton should look disabled

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `AppBarToggleButton`, which has an `Image` set as content (the icon of the button). The source of the image is a SVG-file. When the button gets disabled, unfortunately, the icon stays black. Is it possible to gray out the icon too?

[image: text is grayed out, the icon not]
[image]
(text is grayed out, the icon not)

```
<AppBarToggleButton x:Name="spellCheckingToggleButton" Label="Rechtschreibprüfung">
  <AppBarToggleButton.Content>
    <Image Source="/Assets/SpellChecking2.svg"></Image>
  </AppBarToggleButton.Content>
</AppBarToggleButton>
```

Comment: I have tested it with a few other svg icons, but I never got the expected result. See the screenshot in my edited question too see how it looks with the inbox-icon of Stackoverflow. Do you have any explanation why it could look different in my tests?

Comment: I misunderstood your questions earlier. I thought you mean the SVG shows gray when the button is disabled.  The SVG image should keep black. This is expected. The image control is not the same as SymbolIcon.

Comment: It it possible to change this behaviour in any way?

Comment: The answer is no. If you really want to implement this, you could try to use two different SVG images, one is normal and another is gray. Then replace the normal one with the gray one when the button is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround so that the icon appears disabled too. I converted the icon(s) to an icon font, which I used in a `FontIcon`.

```
<AppBarToggleButton x:Name="spellCheckingToggleButton" Label="Rechtschreibprüfung">
  <AppBarToggleButton.Content>
    <FontIcon FontFamily="Assets/iconfont.ttf#iconfont"  Glyph="&#xe900;" />
  </AppBarToggleButton.Content>
</AppBarToggleButton>
```